# Different views according to if/else statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a if else statement in codeigniter and try to direct different view but its gives error to me.However when i echo it prints to screen

This works !

```
 public function kayitEmailOnay() {

        $registrationCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if ($registrationCode == '') {
            echo "URLde onay kodu yok";
        }


        $registrationConfirmed = $this->kayitmodel->uyeOnay($registrationCode);

        if ($registrationConfirmed)
            echo "true";
        else
            echo "false";
    }
```

This does not work

```
  public function kayitSon() {
        $this->load->view("kayit/kayitTamamla");
    }
    public function kayitHata() {
        $this->load->view("kayit/kayitHata");
    }


    public function kayitEmailOnay() {

        $registrationCode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        if ($registrationCode == '') {
            echo "URLde onay kodu yok";
        }


        $registrationConfirmed = $this->kayitmodel->uyeOnay($registrationCode);

        if ($registrationConfirmed)
            kayitSon();
        else
            kayitHata();
    }
```

The error is that :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should call your function like this:

```
$this->kayitSon();
$this->kayitHata();
```

Answer (score 1):

Class method is called with the object or the object reference. if you are calling a class method inside that class use `$this` keyword

Try calling with `$this`

```
$this->kayitSon();
```